# python object() takes no parameters error

Tags: python

I can't believe this is actually a problem, but I've been trying to debug this error and I've gotten nowhere. I'm sure I'm missing something really simple because this seems so silly.

```
import Experiences, Places, Countries
class Experience(object):

    def make_place(self, place):
        addr = place["address"]
        addr = Places.ttypes.Address(addr["street"], addr["city"], addr["state"], Countries.ttypes._NAMES_TO_VALUES[addr["country"]], addr["zipcode"])
        ll = Geocoder.geocode(addr["street"]+", "+addr["city"]+", "+addr["state"]+" "+addr["zipcode"])
        place["location"] = Places.ttypes.Location(ll[0].coordinates[0], ll[0].coordinates[1])

    def __init__(self, exp_dict):
        exp_dict["datetimeInterval"] = Experiences.ttypes.DateTimeInterval(remove(exp_dict, "startTime"), remove(exp_dict, "endTime"))
        exp_dict["type"] = Experiences.ttypes.ExperienceType.OPEN
        exp_dict["place"] = self.make_place(exp_dict["place"])
        self.obj = Experiences.ttypes.Experience(**exp_dict)

@client.request
@client.catchClientException
def addExperience(thrift, access_token, exp_dict):
    experience = Experience(exp_dict)
    return thrift.client.addExperience(thrift.CLIENT_KEY, access_token, experience.obj)
```

(The two decorators corresponding to addExperience are because this is defined outside of the file where its class is declared.)

The error I'm getting is:

```
experience = Experience(exp_dict)
TypeError: object() takes no parameters
```

So this doesn't make any sense to me because I'm clearly declaring a second argument to the init function. Any help would be awesome!

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/phil/Hangify/hy-frontend-server/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1836, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/Users/phil/Hangify/hy-frontend-server/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in wsgi_app
    response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
  File "/Users/phil/Hangify/hy-frontend-server/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1403, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/Users/phil/Hangify/hy-frontend-server/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/Users/phil/Hangify/hy-frontend-server/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1477, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/Users/phil/Hangify/hy-frontend-server/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1381, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/Users/phil/Hangify/hy-frontend-server/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1475, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/Users/phil/Hangify/hy-frontend-server/env/lib/python2.7/site-    packages/flask/app.py", line 1461, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/Users/phil/Hangify/hy-frontend-server/hangify/session.py", line 22, in check_login
    return f()
  File "/Users/phil/Hangify/hy-frontend-server/hangify/handlers/create.py", line 31, in Handle
    res = exp.addExperience(hangify.thrift_interface, access_token, experience)
  File "/Users/phil/Hangify/hy-frontend-server/hangify/client/__init__.py", line 22, in decorator
    obj = func(client, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/phil/Hangify/hy-frontend-server/hangify/client/__init__.py", line 30, in decorator
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/phil/Hangify/hy-frontend-server/hangify/client/exp.py", line 39, in addExperience
    experience = Experience(exp_dict)
TypeError: object() takes no parameters
```

Here is Experience.mro() - which says the correct module-wise location of the class Experience:

```
[<class 'hangify.client.exp.Experience'>, <type 'object'>]
```

And here is dir(Experience):

```
 ['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__format__',
 '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__module__', '__new__',
 '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__',
 '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', 'make_place']
```

Comment: What is `Experiences` and what is `Experiences.ttypes`?

Comment: Experiences is imported

Comment: But that's not relevant I think. For instance, when I removed object from the inheritance chain, the error became `TypeError: this constructor takes no arguments`

Comment: What do you mean when you say "these definitions are located outisde the file where its class is declared"?  Do you mean that `addExperience` is defined in a different file from the `Experience` class?

Comment: That's weird. I copypasted and this works fine (well until I run into issues with dependencies). Do you get no traceback?

Comment: Sorry, addExperience is a class method. The two wrappers (among other things) give it access to self - which is renamed "thrift".

Comment: @phileaton: A class method of what class?  I suspect that `Experience(exp_dict)` is not referring to the class you think it is.  Can you create a self-contained example demonstrating the problem?

Comment: Can you show the full traceback of your exception? Unless `Experience` has been redefined in whatever namespace contains `addExperience`, that exception doesn't make sense.

Comment: The error could also be in other function calls made during the initialization process, but without more information we're only guessing.

Comment: @BrenBarn, when I changed the name from Experience to foo(exp_dict), it gave the same error - I also changed the class name to foo. So I do believe it is the class I think it is.

Comment: Could you print `Experience.mro()`?

Answer (score 91, accepted):

You've mixed tabs and spaces. `__init__` is actually defined nested inside another method, so your class doesn't have its own `__init__` method, and it inherits `object.__init__` instead. Open your code in Notepad instead of whatever editor you're using, and you'll see your code as Python's tab-handling rules see it.

This is why you should never mix tabs and spaces. Stick to one or the other. Spaces are recommended.

Answer (score 49):

I struggled for a while about this. Stupid rule for `__init__`. It is two "_" together to be "__"

Comment: Got this error because I was sloppy and only wrote `__init()`

Comment: In my case __init_() - what a lame bug :D Self looking 1h vs SO 3m to solve problem :P

Answer (score 34):

I too got this error. Incidentally, i typed **__int__** instead of **__init__**.

I think,  in many mistype cases the IDE i am using (IntelliJ) would have changed the color to the default set for Function definition. But, in my case **__int__** being another dunder/magic method, color remained same as the one which IDE displays for **__init__** (default Predefined item definition color), which took me some time in spotting the missing **i**.

Comment: lol, I did the same mistake and couldn't find it. Your comment helped me to cross check the default method I used. Thanks :)

Comment: Can't believe SO helps you even with _typos_. Cheers.

Answer (score 12):

You must press twice on tap and (<kbd>_</kbd>) key each time,  it must look like:

```
__init__
```

Comment: Question contains the right `__init__`.