# Class Object Error with Tkinter Game From Python for Kids book http://python-for-kids.com

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, tkinter, python-3.6

I am copying a game from a book on learning python called Python For Kids.
The website for the book is [python for kids](http://python-for-kids.com). The code is shown below.

```
from tkinter import *
import random 
import time 
 
class Ball:
    def _init_(self, canvas, color):
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.id = canvas.create_oval(10, 10, 25, 25, fill=color)
        self.canvas.move(self.id, 245, 100)
    def draw(self):
       pass
   
tk = Tk()
tk.title('Game')
tk.resizable(0,0)
tk.wm_attributes('-topmost, 1')
canvas = Canvas(tk, width=500, height=400, bd=0, highlightthickness=0)
canvas.pack()
tk.update()
ball = Ball(canvas, 'red')
while 1:
    tk.update_idletasks()
    tk.update()
    time.sleep(0.01)
```

There were some additional spaces in the program in order to make it easier to understand, but I will forgo these spaces in this question. The error is shown below.

```
=============== RESTART: /Users/gg-mac/Documents/paddleball.py 
===============        
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/gg-mac/Documents/paddleball.py", line 22, in <module>
    ball = Ball(canvas, 'red')
   TypeError: object() takes no parameters
>>>
```

I would appreciate it if you could help. If you can, thank you for your assistance.

Comment: `'_init_' != '__init__'`

Comment: Please fix the formatting of your code here & make sure it's identical with what's on your machine. There are a couple of problems with your code. Firstly, a `*` got lost from your import statements. Next, that method needs to be named `__init__`, not `_init_`. And you left off the closing quote in `tk.wm_attributes('-topmost, 1)`. Also, it's not a good idea to run Tkinter code inside IDLE: it uses Tkinter itself, and things can get confused.

Comment: You have the same error as this question:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23176597/python-object-takes-no-parameters-error

Comment: Thank you for your assistance. I apologize for not writing the code exactly as it was in the book. I made some errors when I was writing the comment, including the closing quote and the asterisk, due to unattentive writing, but those errors were not made in the actual code. Again, thank you very much for your assistance and for the corrections you made.

Answer (score 0):

looks like your class isn't defined correctly. No capital for "c" in class and no parenthesis for the class itself... Correct would be:

```
class Ball():
```

also, it seems later you call the class Canvas, but you don't seem to have any imports of Tk or Canvas here in the snippet. So in order to use Canvas you must import it from somewhere. It would look something like this:

```
from somewhere import Canvas
```

Comment: The `import` statements are there, they just got mangled slightly, and omitted from the code block. And in Python 3, you don't need parentheses after the class name (unless you're deriving from some other class(es)).