# object() takes no parameters in Python 3.4.0

Tags: python

Why do I get this error when trying to run the following code?

> cObj1 = Car("Ford", "Black") TypeError: object() takes no parameters

```
class Car(object):
  numwheels = 4
  def display(self):
    print("Make:", self.make)
    print("Colour:", self.colour)
    print("Wheels:", Car.numwheels)

#main program
cObj1 = Car("Ford", "Black")
cObj1.display()
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: cObj1 = Car("Ford", "Black")
TypeError: object() takes no parameters

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python object() takes no parameters error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23176597/python-object-takes-no-parameters-error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do:

```
class Car:
    numwheels = 4
    def __init__(self, make, colour):
        self.make = make
        self.colour = colour

    def display(self):
      print("Make:", self.make)
      print("Colour:", self.colour)
      print("Wheels:", Car.numwheels)

#main program
cObj1 = Car("Ford", "Black")
cObj1.display()
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Make: Ford
Colour: Black
Wheels: 4
```

Few things with your code:

1- You don't have to inherit from `object` in Python implicitly.

2- You have to initialize all your instance properties before using them. That is usually done inside the `__init__` method.

I really recommend you make a fast read https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html

Comment: Thank you, the mistake I was making was that I did not initialize my instances.