# Apache Beam Issue with p.run() Function

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am running into an issue in one of my Apache Beam scripts. At the moment, it is still a draft and am running it on DirectRunner. But I keep receiving an error that doesn't make sense to me. This is an abbreviated version of my script:

```
options = PipelineOptions()
p = TestPipeline(options = options)
bill_info = (p
             | 'Create Pcollection' >> beam.Create('a')
             | 'Reformatting' >> beam.ParDo(ReformatAttributesFn())
             | 'Scrub First Name' >> beam.ParDo(ScrubFnameFn())
             | 'Scrub Last Name' >> beam.ParDo(ScrubLnameFn())
             | 'Fix Nickname' >> beam.Map(add_nickname, n_tbl=beam.pvalue.AsList(nickname_tbl_ex), return_n=False)
             | 'Check Sponsor' >> beam.Map(check_pol, p_tbl=beam.pvalue.AsList(pol_tbl_ex))
             | 'Check Bill' >> beam.Map(check_bill, b_tbl=beam.pvalue.AsList(bill_tbl_ex))
             | 'Final Formatting' >> beam.ParDo(FinalFormatFn())
             | 'Write To Text' >> beam.io.WriteToText('C:/Users/cmatt/Downloads/test_bill_votes', 
file_name_suffix='.csv'))
p.run()
```

The error I'm receiving is "TypeError: object() takes no parameters" on the p.run() function. But even with the most basic pipeline, such as this:

```
options = PipelineOptions()
p = TestPipeline(options = options)
bill_info = (p
             | 'Create Pcollection' >> beam.Create('a'))
p.run()
```

I still get the same error coming back. Now the pipeline object isn't supposed to take any inputs; it's just a method to run all PCollections through the pipeline. But what part of my script would be causing the error? Is it that some of the modules in my virtual environment aren't lining up correctly? Or is there a separate issue that I am not seeing?

Thanks for the help everyone!

Answer (score 0):

There is no enough context on your python script execution. The fact that you also receive the same error with a basic Dataflow instruction makes me think that your script has a mistake related to python itself, for example '[mixed tabs and spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23183022/9457843)', do you have something like this?

I just make a quick test from the python command line and it worked (steps taken from [Quickstart Using Python](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/quickstarts/quickstart-python)):

```
>>> import apache_beam as beam
>>> from apache_beam.pipeline import PipelineOptions
>>> options = PipelineOptions()
>>> p = beam.Pipeline(options=options)
>>> bill_info = (p | 'Create Pcollection' >> beam.Create(['a','b']))
>>> p.run()
<apache_beam.runners.portability.fn_api_runner.RunnerResult object at 0x7fb57856d290>
>>>
```

If the information above doesn't help, could you share the whole basic script you are executing and how you set your virtual environment? It will help to replicate.

Comment: I was able to resolve the issue. It definitely had something to do with how the packages were downloading and there was some conflict in the nomenclature. I opened up a clean virtual environment in PyCharm and managing the packages was a lot cleaner. Everything was able to run then. Appreciate the help!